# Magento 2 :How to change or update request data using beforeExecute plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, before-plugin

i just want to change some request params by using beforeExecute plugin so can i do same.... ?

**etc/di.xml**
**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword">
    <plugin name="create_password_bug_fixed" type="Vendor\Base\Plugin\Account\CreatePassword" sortOrder="1"  />
</type>
```

**

CreatePassword.php(Plugin Class)

```
    namespace Vendor\Base\Plugin\Account;

class CreatePassword{
    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword $subject){
        /*What need to write here for change attribute value like Token and id */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
$subject->getRequest()->setParam('existing_key', $newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

complete code for post values:-

create befure plugin of your funtion in which receiving form post.

```
public function beforeExecute(
        \Vendor\Moduled\Controller\Path\Path\Save $subject
    ) {
        $date = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue('expired_at') != "" ? $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue('expired_at')  : 'Dec 31, 2050';
        $subject->getRequest()->setPostValue('expired_at', $date);

        return [$subject];
    }
```

In above example I am checking if expired_at is empty change it to Dec 31, 2050